# Ruby: How to traverse YAML node tree with non-unique values?

Tags: ruby

I have a YAML document which I believe is valid (at least it would be
representable in XML):

```
purchase_order:
  date: 10/12/2010
  vendor: 12345
  item:
    product: Tomatoes
    quantity: 5
  item:
    product: Eggs
    quantity: 2
```

The problem is that using YAML.read on this produces a Hash in Ruby in which
only one purchase order item occurs because (naturally) it has to be unique.

How else can one traverse the nodes in a YAML document like this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that is not correct YAML for describing an array of items.

That would be this:

```
purchase_order: 
  date: 10/12/2010
  vendor: 12345
  items: 
  - quantity: 5
    product: Tomatoes
  - quantity: 2
    product: Eggs
```

So I don't think you will be able to parse it as YAML.

Perhaps parsing it as a text file with a YAML-like structure is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to parse this with YAML.load, but it still discards the first item, thusly: {"purchase_order"=>{"date"=>"10/12/2010", "vendor"=>12345, "item"=>{"quantity"=>2, "product"=>"Eggs"}}}

Comment: Parsing this for me gives: {"purchase_order"=>{"items"=>[{"quantity"=>5, "product"=>"Tomatoes"}, {"quantity"=>2, "product"=>"Eggs"}], "date"=>"10/12/2010", "vendor"=>12345}}. I don't see how you could have got what you have above as this YAML contains no key 'item'